# Change selected element back to main base using Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am creating a select box that when I select a value in main select box Domains, it will appear other select box Types like Diatoms or Flagellates.... I am done with that part however, I am trying to change back the selected item in a select box that new appear to the main first one. I mean when I selected a Diatoms in Domains select box and it will appear then I select some item in Diatoms. Then I change other items in Domains and other select box will appear, the Diatoms will disappear. But the thing is the selected item that I select still remain like when I select it, I want to change it back to first option default, not the item. Here is my code

I already tried to put 'selectedIndex', 0. However it not work.

HTML

```
<ul class="inline_list">
    <li class="Domains">
        <select>
            <option selected disabled hidden>Domains</option>
            <option value="Diatoms">Diatoms</option>
            <option value="Flagellates">Flagellates</option>
            <option value="Dinoflagellates">Dinoflagellates</option>
            <option value="Ciliates">Ciliates</option>
            <option value="Coccolithophore">Coccolithophore</option>
            <option value="Miscellaneous">Miscellaneous</option>
            <option value="Other_plankton">Others</option>
        </select>
    </li>
    <li class="Diatoms domains_types">
        <select>
            <option selected disabled hidden>Types</option>
            <option value="Asterionellopsis">Asterionellopsis</option>
            <option value="Bacillaria">Bacillaria</option>
        </select>
    </li>
    <li class="Flagellates domains_types">
        <select>
            <option selected disabled hidden>Types</option>
            <option value="amoeba">amoeba</option>
            <option value="Chrysochromulina">Chrysochromulina</option>
        </select>
    </li>
    <script src="js/select_box.js"></script>
</ul>
```

CSS

```
.domains_types{
            display: none;
        }
```

Jquery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.Domains').ready(function(){
        $('select').change(function(){
            $("select option:selected").each(function(){
                if($(this).attr("value")=="Diatoms"){
                    $('.domains_types').hide();
                    $('.Diatoms').css('display','inline-block');
                }
                if($(this).attr("value")=="Flagellates"){
                    $('.domains_types').hide();
                    $('.Flagellates').css('display','inline-block');
                }
            });
        }).change();
    });
});
```

Comment: Side notes; `ready()` is meant to be used off of a document, not an element, so `$('.Domains').ready(function(){` is pointless and should be removed.  `$(this).attr('value')` is an unnecessary usage of jQuery as you already have the Element.  Use `this.value` instead.  Also `$("select option:selected")` inside the change handler is too broad.  Inside the change handler `this` will be the select that was changed.  `$('option:selected', this)` will find the selected option in the changed select.  No need to loop over all the selects to get the one that changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You code can be easily optimised to reduce the redundancy in your code. Some straightforward improvements that we can do are:

- Removing the `ready` event listener from `$('.Domains')`. The ready function is specific to the document object only, which maps to the `DOMContentLoaded` event. It's simply a convenience method made available by jQuery.
- Instead of iterating through all options, you can simply get the value of the `<select>` element by calling `this.value`. This removes one layer of nesting form your code
- Instead of creating a new `if` statement for each possible value, you can actually just use `'.' + this.value` to select the correct element, since you have one-to-one mapping of the first `<select>` elements options values to the `<li>` wrapper for the second level of `<select>` elements. For example, if the value selected is `Flagellates`, then the selector will select for `$('.' + this.value)` which evaluates to `$('.Flagellates')`
- To "reset" your second level of `<select>` element, simply select the first option and set its `selected` property to true, i.e. `$('option:first-child').prop('selected, true')`.
- `hidden` is not an attribute/property of an `<option>` element. You can remove it.

With that in mind, here is the improved and working code:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.Domains select').change(function() {
    $('.domains_types')
      .hide()                            // Hide the <li> element
      .find('select option:first-child') // Get the nested select's first option
      .prop('selected', true);           // Select it
      
    $('.' + this.value).css('display', 'inline-block');
  }).change();
});
```

```css
.domains_types {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="inline_list">
  <li class="Domains">
    <select>
      <option selected disabled>Domains</option>
      <option value="Diatoms">Diatoms</option>
      <option value="Flagellates">Flagellates</option>
      <option value="Dinoflagellates">Dinoflagellates</option>
      <option value="Ciliates">Ciliates</option>
      <option value="Coccolithophore">Coccolithophore</option>
      <option value="Miscellaneous">Miscellaneous</option>
      <option value="Other_plankton">Others</option>
    </select>
  </li>
  <li class="Diatoms domains_types">
    <select>
      <option selected disabled>Types</option>
      <option value="Asterionellopsis">Asterionellopsis</option>
      <option value="Bacillaria">Bacillaria</option>
    </select>
  </li>
  <li class="Flagellates domains_types">
    <select>
      <option selected disabled>Types</option>
      <option value="amoeba">amoeba</option>
      <option value="Chrysochromulina">Chrysochromulina</option>
    </select>
  </li>
</ul>
```